# How to cast varchar to int in sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2000

I have table called `ExamInfo`. In that table the column `Sub1` is of the type `VARCHAR(50)`. The Sub1 column contains **numeric**, **null** and **non-numeric** data.

I want to select from ExamInfo where the data in Sub1 is greater than 81.

Here is my query:

```
select * 
from Exam 
where cast(sub1 as int) > 81`.
```

But it fails to cast resulting in an error.

Comment: Could you specify which database server you are running on?

Comment: **WHAT** is the error you're getting?? We can't see your screen - we can't read your mind - you need to **tell us!**

Answer (score 4):

Since your column contains mixed information and the cast is applied to the whole column, you need to make sure you only attempt to cast actual numeric values:

```
select * 
from Exam 
where case when ISNUMERIC(sub1) =1
            and CHARINDEX('.', sub1) = 0 
            and sub1 >= -2147483648 
            and sub1 <= 2147483647
           then cast(sub1 as int) 
           else 0 
      end > 81
```

This is an example on how to do it in SQL Server.

There is one more point of attention in this query and that is "Globalization". The '.' we are checking for as decimal point is not everywhere used as decimal point. If you have a localized SQL Server you can grab the correct decimal separator by doing

```
DECLARE @decimal_separator char(1)
set @decimal_separator = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(3), CONVERT(NUMERIC(2,1), 1.0/2)), 2, 1)
```

Which would turn the query into:

```
DECLARE @decimal_separator char(1)
set @decimal_separator = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(3), CONVERT(NUMERIC(2,1), 1.0/2)), 2, 1)

select * 
from Exam 
where case when ISNUMERIC(sub1) =1
            and CHARINDEX(@decimal_separator, sub1) = 0 
            and sub1 >= -2147483648 
            and sub1 <= 2147483647
           then cast(sub1 as int) 
           else 0 
      end > 81
```

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` does not return a boolean. You need to test whether it is `1`. And even then it doesn't guarantee that it will cast to `int` successfully.

Comment: I am getting error.Error is Incorrect syntax near keyword then.

Comment: It will indeed not test if it is an int. (and fixed the syntax error)

Comment: I added more checks for Integer values, and some more detail on how localized SQL Servers need to be handled.

Comment: Thanks Filip De Vos.It is working properly.There is no decimal part in my table.So I remove that code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some of the data in sub1 cannot be cast as an int. Check the data for non numeric data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM ExamInfo
 WHERE  CAST( (CASE 
                WHEN ISNUMERIC(Sub1) <> 1 
                    THEN NULL
                --Ignore any decimal value
                WHEN ISNUMERIC(Sub1 + '.0e0') <> 1                  
                    THEN NULL
                WHEN CAST(Sub1 AS NUMERIC(38, 0)) BETWEEN -2147483648 AND 2147483647
                    THEN Sub1       
                ELSE null 
              END) AS INT ) > 81;
```